# Loading image on Laravel localhost not working

Tags: html, css, laravel, background-image

When trying to load my image on laravel, the image is loaded in back-end fine. But not showing on the web page.

This is my code:

```
<figure class="c-card__image c-card__image--arrow c-searchresult__image"style="background-image: url('{{$image}}?{{\Carbon\Carbon::now()->timestamp}}')"></figure>
```

This is the code in browser:

```
<figure class="c-card__image c-card__image--arrow c-searchresult__image" style="background-image: url('/vendors/57/horse-11.png?1554287941')"></figure>
```

In my Console & Network tab (from browser) I can see the image is loaded correctly.. but it's not shown on screen..

Comment: what is the output of `dd($image);` and also specify the full path of your image?

Comment: The page is not loading when I do dd($image) in the view or controller.
full path is "/Users/sg/a-website/public/vendors/57/horse-11.png"

Answer (score 0):

In the code above you are not specifying any file type that may be the issue, it should be something like this `horse-11.png?1554287941.png` or `horse-11?1554287941.png`.Your `$image` var should only save the name, that way you can do something like this:

```
<figure class="c-card__image c-card__image--arrow c-searchresult__image"style="background-image: url('{{$image}}?{{\Carbon\Carbon::now()->timestamp}}'.'png')"></figure>
```

and the output will be something like this

```
<figure class="c-card__image c-card__image--arrow c-searchresult__image" style="background-image: url('/vendors/57/horse-11?1554287941.png')"></figure>
```